# I can't seem to get tkinter grid to resize

Tags: python, tkinter

I've spent the last few days trying to get grid() to resize my window correctly. I've gotten it to resize if I just use pack(), but grid() has got to be able to do this, too, right?

As a last resort, I've rewritten my code to just display a Quit button. Yet when I resize the window, the Quit button just stays in the corner! With pack(), it will move to the centre of the window, as the window expands.

I've added the calls to `grid_columnconfigure()` and `grid_rowconfigure()`, but that doesn't seem to do anything. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks...

```
from Tkinter import *

class myBase(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # By inheriting from Tk, this is already the "root":
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


        # Build the base container, which itself is a frame:
        container = Frame(self)
        container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="eswn")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


        # This is the "series" of frames (pages):
        self.frames = {}

        # Create instances of each "page":
        for page in (myPage01, myPage02):
            frame = page(container, self)
            self.frames[page] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="eswn")


        # This is the first page:
        self.showFrame(myPage01)


    def showFrame(self, pageObject):

        # Finds the correct frame (page), and "raises" it:
        frame = self.frames[pageObject]
        frame.tkraise()



class myPage01(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, objCall):

        # Inheriting from a frame, so initialize that part first:
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)


        # "Pointer" to the calling object:
        self.objCall = objCall


        # Create the widgets for a simple login screen:
        buttonQuit = Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.quit, width=10)


        # Place everything on the grid:
        buttonQuit.grid(row=0, column=0)


        # Shortcut to put some nice padding around each widget:
        for child in self.winfo_children():
            child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)


        # Some key bindings:
        buttonQuit.bind("<Return>", self.hQuit)

    def hQuit(self, event):
        self.quit()


class myPage02(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, objCall):

        # Inheriting from a frame, so initialize that part first:
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)


        # "Pointer" to the calling object:
        self.objCall = objCall


        # Create the widgets for a simple login screen:
        buttonQuit = Button(self, text="Out", command=self.quit, width=10)


        # Place everything on the grid:
        buttonQuit.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="W")


        # Shortcut to put some nice padding around each widget:
        for child in self.winfo_children():
            child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)


        # Some key bindings:
        buttonQuit.bind("<Return>", self.hQuit)

    def hQuit(self, event):
        self.quit()



app = myBase()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: if `pack()` works then why do you use `grid()` ? `pack()`, `grid()` and `place()` were created to manage layout in different way. You can put `Frame` using `pack()` and then use `grid()` inside this frame.

Comment: You say you call rowconfigure and columnconfigure, but I don't see where you're calling that for the frame with the quit button. Also, is it really necessary to have two "pages" to reproduce this problem? It's hard to tell which frame you're having problems with since there are so many frames. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then remove all of the code that isn't strictly necessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi - yes, you're right. I just figured it out after reading the New Mexico Tech tkinter tutorial. I had to first call rowconfigure and columnconfigure on the top level window AND then call these for each frame (page). I thought calling grid_rowconfigure was the same thing. The only problem I get now is that the resize is all whacky...

Comment: To the earlier question of why I'm using grid() if pack() works...just screwing around. Everywhere I've read says that grid() is superior to pack(), so I just didn't see why I couldn't do it....